# I can't make a manually output of my table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, pivot

I have transactions table,

```
id transaction_date status
1  2020-01-01       Shipped
2  2020-02-01       Shipped
3  2020-02-01       Cancelled
```

I wish to convert this like a pivot table in excel, so it looks like below

```
Date       SHIPPED CANCELLED PROCESSING
2020-01-01 1       0         0
2020-02-01 1       1         0
```

I'm completely clueless in approaching this. What function should I use?

Comment: you _could_ handle the conditionals with `case`, but the syntax is more unwieldy than the `sum(status='whatever')` below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation, as in:

```
select
  date,
  sum(status = 'Shipped') as shipped,
  sum(status = 'Cancelled') as cancelled,
  sum(status = 'Processing') as processing
from t
group by date
```

In MySQL a predicate (that normally evaluates to a boolean value) also evaluates to an `INT`, as `0` for false, and `1` for true.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    date,
    sum(status = 'Shipped')   shipped,
    sum(status = 'Cancelled') cancelled,
    sum(status = 'Processing') processing
from mytable
group by date
```